# How to pass an exit code from custom testing framework to CircleCI in order to fail the step if necessary

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, godot

I created the automated testing plugin for Godot named [WAT](https://github.com/CodeDarigan/WAT). It has a command line interface that outputs 0 (success) or 1 (failure) on the last line when run.

I'm looking for a way to pass that number onto CircleCI so that the step fails if it was 1.

I'm working in a bash environment with the following config.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: barichello/godot-ci:3.1.1

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: godot -s addons/WAT/CLI.gd -run_all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`OS.exit_code`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_os.html#class-os-property-exit-code) to a non-zero number and the step should fail.

If that is not acceptable, you can parse your output and fail manually from Bash with `exit 1`.